# How to use subquery with group by in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, subquery, min

> I have one table with multiple rows for particular users.i am having 
>   data with many years like 2019,2018,2016 and more. i have two 
>   scenarios:
>
> 1.i want data of particular INVOICE_YEAR.
>
> 2,but same time i want FIRST DATE OF INVOICE GENERATED FOR PARTICULAR
>   USER.

my sql query :

`$yearOf` this is dynamic year input variable.

`$yearOf` = 2019;

```
$Records = "SELECT MIN(inv.INVOICE_DATE) AS MIN_INVOICE_DATE
                    FROM invoices as inv
                    LEFT JOIN customers as cm ON cm.CUSTOMER_ID = inv.CUSTOMER_ID 
                    where inv.INVOICE_YEAR IN (".$yearOf.")
                    group by inv.CUSTOMER_ID ORDER BY cm.CUSTOMER_NAME ASC";
```

As you can see my query if i want data of all users where INVOICE_YEAR IN ('2019').My first condition will satisfied i will get all data of users where INVOICE_YEAR = 2019.

But same time i want first invoice date so for this i used `MIN(inv.INVOICE_DATE)` but as i used
`where inv.INVOICE_YEAR IN (".$yearOf.")` this in where condition so it gives me first invoice date of particular year.

But i want first invoice date from  whole table for all users.

I tried with subquery but it shows me error of **Subquery returns more than 1 row**

My query with subquery:

```
$Records = "SELECT 
                    (
                    SELECT MIN(inv.INVOICE_DATE) AS MIN_INVOICE_DATE FROM invoices AS inv GROUP BY inv.CUSTOMER_ID) AS MIN_INVOICE_DATE
                    FROM invoices as inv 
                    LEFT JOIN customers as cm ON cm.CUSTOMER_ID = inv.CUSTOMER_ID 
                    where inv.INVOICE_YEAR IN (".$yearOf.")
                    group by inv.CUSTOMER_ID ORDER BY cm.CUSTOMER_NAME ASC";
```

For eg:

3 customers are there 101,102,103

data in table is like:

```
id | customer_id | invoice_date | invoice_year
1  | 101         | 2019-01-01   |  2019
2  | 101         | 2016-01-01   |  2016
3  | 101         | 2017-01-01   |  2017
4  | 101         | 2016-01-02   |  2016
5  | 102         | 2019-01-02   |  2019
6  | 103         | 2018-01-02   |  2018
7  | 103         | 2019-01-07   |  2019
8  | 102         | 2015-01-02   |  2015
```

As i Request query to get data of INVOICE_YEAR 2019 with first invoice date of particular user so it should give output like :

```
id | customer_id | invoice_date | invoice_year | min_invoice_date
1  | 101         | 2019-01-01   |  2019        | 2016-01-01
5  | 102         | 2019-01-02   |  2019        | 2015-01-02
7  | 103         | 2019-01-07   |  2019        | 2019-01-07
```

With as i want ***first invoice date IN COLUMN MIN_INVOICE_DATE*** of all users.

But it shows me data like :

```
id | customer_id | invoice_date | invoice_year | min_invoice_date
1  | 101         | 2019-01-01   |  2019        | 2019-01-01
5  | 102         | 2019-01-02   |  2019        | 2019-01-02
7  | 103         | 2019-01-07   |  2019        | 2019-01-07
```

Comment: Please add sample data and expected results to clarify your question.

Comment: @GMB please view my added example to know my question in brief thanks

Comment: [I removed the blockquote](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58354698/2) earlier. Why did you add those back in again?

Comment: You only expect 1 row per user even if there are many invoices for that user in 2019? If yes which one would you show?

Comment: Blockquote is for error messages or quoting something, not for your own personal highlighting enjoyment. Why are you using those? I feel like I've fallen onto deaf ears.

Comment: For future reference, when you get answers on StackOverflow and you're tempted to reply that the person did not understand your question, it means, with respect, that **your question is not clear.**. In such cases please [edit] your question.  And please read about rubber duck debugging. https://rubberduckdebugging.com/  Often the task of writing a clear question can lead you to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to pull out the earliest invoice for each customer in 2019, along with the date of their earliest invoice within the whole table.

In MySQL 8.0, you can solve this using window functions:

```
SELECT id, customer_id, invoice_date, invoice_year, min_invoice_date
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id, invoice_year ORDER BY invoice_date) rn,
        MIN(invoice_date) OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id) min_invoice_date
    FROM mytable t
) x
WHERE invoice_year = 2019 AND rn = 1
```

In earlier versions, you can:

- `JOIN` the table with a query that computes the overall minimum `invoice_date` per customer
- use a correlated subquery with a `NOT EXISTS` condition to filter on the earliest invoice par customer in 2019

Query:

```
SELECT t.id, t.customer_id, t.invoice_date, t.invoice_year, m.min_invoice_date
FROM mytable t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT customer_id, MIN(invoice_date) min_invoice_date 
    FROM mytable 
    GROUP BY customer_id
) m ON m.customer_id = t.customer_id
WHERE 
    t.invoice_year = 2019
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM mytable t1
        WHERE t1.invoice_year = 2019 
        AND t1.customer_id = t.customer_id
        AND t1.invoice_date < t.invoice_date
    )
```

In this **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7tUMWBbWWxzqP9PHV2RLMc/1)**, both queries return:

```
| id  | customer_id | invoice_date | invoice_year | min_invoice_date |
| --- | ----------- | ------------ | ------------ | ---------------- |
| 1   | 101         | 2019-01-01   | 2019         | 2016-01-01       |
| 5   | 102         | 2019-01-02   | 2019         | 2015-01-02       |
| 7   | 103         | 2019-01-07   | 2019         | 2018-01-02       |
```

Comment: thanks for your reply bro but still you cant undestand my question. @GMB

Comment: @amitsutar: I gave a second look at your question and updated my answer. As far as concerned, the new queries do produce the expected result for your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I *guess* you want the to see the details of the first (earliest-dated) invoice for each customer in each calendar year.  You want that result filtered to cover only one year.

So, start with a subquery to find the *date* of the first invoice for every customer in each calendar year. (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bmBZ14Vr9Re6ahpfs2FF2X/0)

```
      SELECT MIN(invoice_date) first_invoice_date,
             YEAR(invoice_date) calendar_year,
             customer_id
        FROM invoices
       GROUP BY YEAR(invoice_date), customer_id
```

Then retrieve the detail for those invoices by JOINing that subquery to your original `invoices` table. (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bmBZ14Vr9Re6ahpfs2FF2X/1)

```
SELECT invoices.*
  FROM invoices
  JOIN (
          SELECT MIN(invoice_date) first_invoice_date,
                 YEAR(invoice_date) calendar_year,
                 customer_id
            FROM invoices
           GROUP BY YEAR(invoice_date), customer_id
       ) firsts 
           ON invoices.customer_id = firsts.customer_id
          AND invoices.invoice_date = firsts.first_invoice_date
  ORDER BY invoices.customer_id, 
           invoices.invoice_year, 
           invoices.invoice_date
```

Then, throw in `WHERE invoices.invoice_year = 2019` to  get just the year you want.

Notice that your `invoice_year` column is unnecessary, since it can always be computed from `YEAR(invoice_date)`. You should consider getting rid of it.

Comment: thanks for your reply bro but your query is not suitable for my question. @O.Jones

Comment: its shows me same MIN_INVOICE_DATE for all customers

Comment: That's strange. In the dbfiddle it shows me different dates for different customers. I based the dbfiddle on your sample data.  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bmBZ14Vr9Re6ahpfs2FF2X/2